# ionic Assign HttpClient response variables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm learning the ionic framework and want to know how REST calls are done correctly.

I have a RestProvider class which gets me a list of products

rest.ts

```
  getProduct(query: string) {
    return this.http.get(searchUri+query)
  }
```

And in my home page I want to assign a value from the response to a local variable

home.ts

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.restProvider.getProduct(query).subscribe(it => {
      console.log(it)
      this.products = it.result;
    })
  }
```

But I get an error on assignment line `this.products = it.result;`

> [ts] Property result does not exist on type Object

How do I create models of my response and assign them to class variables?

Comment: check if 'it' contains a result property, if so check r u accessing that in a valid way

Comment: 'it' is a JSON response and 'it.result' isn't explicitly defined anywhere, how can I do that?

Comment: That'll be because of Typescript. Change the service to `this.http.get<any>(searchUri+query)` and it should work. Better yet, if you have an interface that represents the response, use that instead of `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you get in return is a JSON parsing of the response body. The error is that Typescript does now know if the `result`property exists on the returned type. So you should disambiguate the situation.

You declare the type of the returned object with the template argument to `get` as in `get<MyReturnedType>`. So here, you should provide a template argument containing the `result` property.

Either you know the type for it, then use it, or you don't, then use `any` and you are responsible for the object accesses you make.

You can get more details on this [Angular documentation page](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response).

**Note**: don't use `searchUri+query` as your url because it is not escaped properly. You should instead use `HttpParams` described [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters).